# how to add and use languages in soft keyboard

Tags: android, localization, keyboard

Android supports the localization for keyboard. We can choose the Input method language by

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

But how can we add any particular language into Input method ?
How can we change keyboard input method without showing picker to user ?

Thanks,

Comment: You need not to do anything for keyboard, whenever you will change your phone language. Android will manage for keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use different languages for all string layouts(localization) and than you need to choose the language option manually in your `phone settings` .

You can select any language, for example if you have selected French language than it will take appropriate language to the soft keyboard also.

I hope u understood